# Differential equation in Newton's law of gravitation

Tags: calculus

I have a question in following differential equation:$$m(dv/dt)=-GMm/r^2$$
Using chain rule:$$dv/dt=(dv/dr)*(dr/dt)=v(dv/dr)$$
Then $$v(dv/dr)=-GMm/r^2$$
I don't understand that $dr/dt=v$ because there are two objects, I assume the other object's velocity is $v_2$.

After $\delta t$, distance between two objects' centres $r$ will reduce $\delta (v+v2)$

Then $$dr/dt = v+v_2$$
I don't know if it is wrong. Thanks to all people who offer helps :)

Comment: There is only one object whose velicity is $v.$ The center of gravitation is at rest.

Comment: why is the centre of gravitation at rest? It is still forced

Comment: We take it as frame of reference. See the [usual suspect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation).

Comment: We take it as frame of reference.The velocity is 0, You just move the $v_2$ to the object, Then the object is $v+v_2$

Comment: Maybe one reason why we write $dr/dt=v$ is that $v2$ is too small so we omit it. (I find that my material point out M is earth and m is an object).

Comment: Each object, $m$ and $M$, feels the same magnitude force $F=GMm/r^2$ radially directed towards the other. So, based on that same $F$, you can then use $\vec F=m\vec a$ (or $M\vec a$) to work out their separate accelerations, which you can then add together to get their combined $\ddot r$ if desired.

Comment: @John Forkosh Thanks for help, but this question I just think about it's $dr/dt=v$ or $ v+v_2$

Comment: @TerryYoung I think maybe you're abusing/confusing your $r$ notation. When you write $v(dv/dr)$, that $r$ refers just to the $m$ object's coordinates with respect to some given inertial frame of reference. But then you go on to say, "distance between two objects' centres $r$". That ain't the same $r$.

Comment: It is assumed that $M$ is much larger than $m$ so that the larger object does not move. Consider a binary star system to investigate a case where that is not true.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yeah, I agree.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Yes, I see the same.

Answer (score 0):

This equation, like all equations arising in physics, is a *model*. It does not completely characterize the behavior of the physical system. Rather, it is a good enough approximation to be deemed as useful.

As you know, Newton's law of universal gravitation says that, between any two objects of mass $m_1,m_2$, separated by a distance $d$, there are equal and opposite gravitational forces of magnitude $\frac{Gm_1m_2}{d^2}$ between the two objects, pointing in the direction of their displacement vectors.

Let's now imagine a physical system in which we have these two objects in an isolated environment - empty space if you will.
It turns out that only one differential equation is simply not enough to describe this simple system.

To see why, let's make some constructions. Call the position occupied by object $1$ at time $t$ $\boldsymbol x_1$, and call the position occupied by object $2$ at time $t$ $\boldsymbol x_2$. The first object obeys the following differential equation:
$$\underset{\text{mass}}{m_1}~\underset{\text{accel.}}{\ddot{\boldsymbol x}_1}=\underbrace{Gm_1m_2~\frac{1}{\underset{\text{squared distance}}{\|\boldsymbol x_1-\boldsymbol x_2\|^2}}}_{\text{Net Force}}$$
Similarly, the the second object obeys a nearly identical equation:
$$m_2\ddot{\boldsymbol x}_2=Gm_1m_2~\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol x_1-\boldsymbol x_2\|^2}$$

As you can see, the two equations are coupled - acceleration of the first object depends on the second, and vica versa. This system of **coupled, nonlinear** differential equations are difficult (impossible actually) to solve with pencil and paper, so what do we do? We make an assumption that simplifies the mathematics but remains suitably accurate to be useful.

When studying planetary motion, typically what we have is a large star of mass $M$ (say object 1) and a small planet of mass $m\ll M$ (say object 2). In this case, the acceleration of the small object is much much larger than that of the large object, and so, to simplify our model, we assume that the large object of mass $M$ is stationary. And, because we are assuming object 1 is motionless, we can, without loss of generality, assume it is at the origin. We also make the notation change $\boldsymbol x_2\to\boldsymbol x$ for clarity, and , with all these changes, our second equation simplifies to

$$\ddot{\boldsymbol x}=\frac{GM}{\|\boldsymbol x\|^2}$$